# Installing .NET framework in Wine and Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, wine

I am using Fedora 23. I installed Wine 1.75 in it, but i cannot install .NET  framework 4. When i try to install  framework 4 it shows "already installed a same or higher version". I don't know how to remove the higher version.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is a software installation question, and not a programming question. You may get more help on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Only way to remove dotnet from a wineprefix is manually removing its files. (assuming this does not break something else, which it may)

It is much easier to delete the whole wine folder and start from a new fresh prefix.

Step-by-step and assuming you got wine installed in ~/.wine you should:

- remove existing wine prefix:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/.wine
  ```
- make a new win32 architecture wine prefix (no need to specify
  wineprefix path - it defaults to ~/.wine)

  ```
  WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
  ```

Now, it is *much* easier to have winetricks installed for such tasks, so make sure you do that before going on.

- Afterwards, depending on what dotnet you want, install it like so:

  ```
  winetricks dotnet452
  ```
- or for dotnet 3.5sp1:

  ```
  winetricks dotnet35sp1
  ```
- or whatever other dotnet version you want. You can see all the dlls
  winetricks has scripts on how to install:

  ```
  winetricks dlls list
  ```

Also keep in mind that you don't have to install all previous dotnets one-by-one, the winetricks script will do that for you with usually better results.

Finally remember that if you install dotnet2 and then run winetricks again to install another dotnet on top, it won't work and even if you -f force it.

For further info on the subject, check the [wine app db dotnet 40 entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17886) and the [arch wiki article on wine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wine)

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.